# Need some help on writing SQL query

Tags: oracle11g

Hope you are doing good. I am new to SQL coding. I want to write a query which finds the difference between two tables and writes updates or new data into third table. My two tables have identical column names. Third table which captures changes have extra column called comment. I would like to insert the comment whether it is a new row or updated row based on the row modification.

```
**TABLE1 (BACKUP)**
KEY,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY
1,RAM,KUMAR,INDIA
2,TOM,MOODY,ENGLAND
3,MOHAMMAD,HAFEEZ,PAKISTAN
4,MONIKA,SAM,USA
5,MIKE,PALEDINO,USA

**TABLE2 (CURRENT)**
KEY,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY
1,RAM,KUMAR,USA
2,TOM,MOODY,ENGLAND
3,MOHAMMAD,HAFEEZ,PAKISTAN
4,MONIKA,SAM,INDIA
5,MIKE,PALEDINO,USA
6,MAHELA,JAYA,SL



**TABLE3 (DIFFERENCE FROM TABLE2 TO TABLE1)**
KEY,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY,COMMENT
1,RAM,KUMAR,USA,UPDATE
4,MONIKA,SAM,INDIA,UPDATE
6,MAHELA,JAYA,SL,INSERT
```

---

Anyone else? I want to update my comments columns whether it is a new insert or update to existing row

Answer (score 1):

@danny117 is correct in the general sense though I think using MINUS is better

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

You may also like to look at [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm#SQLRF52323) which explains more about minus, intersect

Comment: Yes, But how to i write something to Comment column when using Table2 Minues Table 1 to Table 3? I would like to capture if it is a update ot new row.

Comment: Assuming Comment exists in another table lets call it table4, you could do (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE1) LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE2.KEY = TABLE4.KEY

Comment: No, It doesn't exist on 4th table. I am making up from the differences between two table whether it is new row inset or update to existing row.

Comment: I think you need to look at ['case'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm#SQLRF52054) for that. I think something like `SELECT *, CASE  WHEN minusTable.CITY  != TABLE2.CITY  THEN 'UPDATE'  ELSE 'INSERT' END  FROM  (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE1) AS minusTable;` . I have not tested it but I hope you get the principle.

Comment: correction `SELECT *, CASE  WHEN minusTable.CITY  != TABLE1.CITY  THEN 'UPDATE'  ELSE 'INSERT' END  FROM  (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE1) AS minusTable;` let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3
SELECT KEY,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY,NULL AS COMMENTS FROM TABLE2
MINUS 
SELECT KEY,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY,NULL AS COMMENTS FROM TABLE1;


UPDATE TABLE3 
SET COMMENTS =
CASE 
WHEN 1=(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.KEY=TABLE3.KEY) THEN 'UPDATED'
ELSE 'INSERTED'
END
```